# SessionStorage value is not getting displayed on first Page load in React App

Tags: session, reactjs, sessionstorage

```
JSX File:
const Action = React.createClass({
   getInitialState() {
      return {actiondrp: [],empDetail:[],show:false,**UserName**:sessionStorage.getItem('UserName')}
   },
   componentWillMount: function () {
      var _this=this;
        _this.setState({UserName:sessionStorage.getItem('UserName')});
        this.fetchBypasses();
       // console.log(UserName);    
   },


HTML: 

  render: function() {
     var that=this;
     return (
        <div>
            <span></span>
            <span>Welcome,{that.state.UserName}</span>
        </div>
     )
  }
```

SessionStorage should appear on first page load but it is coming as null for the first time. If i reload the page, it is coming correctly.

Comment: When you are setting value to sessionstorage?

Comment: Do you have server-side rendering enabled?

Comment: Where you set 'UserName' to `sessionStorage`?

Comment: I am setting the value of SessionStorage in different jsx component. I am able to set and get the value of sessionstorage.